# Graphviz: orientation/position of self loops

Tags: graphviz

I have the follow graph description

```
digraph G {
    nodesep=0.5;

    graph[ label = ""];
    node [ fontname=Arial fontcolor=black fontsize=24 fixedsize=true width=1.0 height=1.0];
    edge [ fontname=Arial fontcolor=black fontsize=24];

    x0 [label = <> pos="0,2!"]
    x1 [label = <> pos="4,2!" ]
    x2 [label = <> pos="2,0!" ]


    edge[style=solid];
    x0:ne -> x0:nw [ label=<1> ]
    x1 -> x0 [ label=<2> ]
    x2 -> x0 [ label=<3> ]
    x0 -> x1 [ label=<4> ]
    x1:ne -> x1:nw [ label=<6> ]
    x2 -> x1 [ label=<7> ]
    x0 -> x2 [ label=<9> ]
    x1 -> x2 [ label=<8> ]
    x2:sw -> x2:se [ label=<0> ]  
}
```

which gives me the following graph

[image]

Mostly fine. However, I cannot seem to find away for the self loop of the node to pass below the node, which would arguably look much nicer. Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can trick it by rearranging nodes and slightly updating edge ports.

```dot
digraph G {
    nodesep=0.5;
    layout="fdp"

    graph[ label = "" ];
    
    node [ fontname=Arial fontcolor=black fontsize=24 fixedsize=true width=1.0 height=1.0];
    edge [ fontname=Arial fontcolor=black fontsize=24];

    x0 [label = <> pos="0,0!"]
    x1 [label = <> pos="4,0!" ]
    x2 [label = <> pos="2,2!" ]


    edge[style=solid];
    x0:sw -> x0:_ [ label=<1> ]
    x1 -> x0 [ label=<2> ]
    x2 -> x0 [ label=<3> ]
    x0 -> x1 [ label=<4> ]
    x1:se -> x1:_ [ label=<6> dir=back]
    x2 -> x1 [ label=<7> ]
    x0 -> x2 [ label=<9> ]
    x1 -> x2 [ label=<8> ]
    x2:nw -> x2:ne [ label=<0> ] 
}
```

[View in editor](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/?dot=digraph%20G%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20nodesep%3D0.5%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20layout%3D%22fdp%22%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20graph%5B%20label%20%3D%20%22%22%20%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5B%20fontname%3DArial%20fontcolor%3Dblack%20fontsize%3D24%20fixedsize%3Dtrue%20width%3D1.0%20height%3D1.0%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20edge%20%5B%20fontname%3DArial%20fontcolor%3Dblack%20fontsize%3D24%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x0%20%5Blabel%20%3D%20%3C%3E%20pos%3D%220%2C0%21%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x1%20%5Blabel%20%3D%20%3C%3E%20pos%3D%224%2C0%21%22%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x2%20%5Blabel%20%3D%20%3C%3E%20pos%3D%222%2C2%21%22%20%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20edge%5Bstyle%3Dsolid%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x0%3Asw%20-%3E%20x0%3A_%20%5B%20label%3D%3C1%3E%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x1%20-%3E%20x0%20%5B%20label%3D%3C2%3E%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x2%20-%3E%20x0%20%5B%20label%3D%3C3%3E%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x0%20-%3E%20x1%20%5B%20label%3D%3C4%3E%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x1%3Ase%20-%3E%20x1%3A_%20%5B%20label%3D%3C6%3E%20dir%3Dback%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x2%20-%3E%20x1%20%5B%20label%3D%3C7%3E%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x0%20-%3E%20x2%20%5B%20label%3D%3C9%3E%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x1%20-%3E%20x2%20%5B%20label%3D%3C8%3E%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x2%3Anw%20-%3E%20x2%3Ane%20%5B%20label%3D%3C0%3E%20%5D%20%0D%0A%7D)

[image]

Comment: Isn't the problem that for more complex situations (more nodes) this won't work anymore and that in this, example, case it just works.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it only helps with this particular situation. More complex graph would need some other creative approach. I doubt Graphviz allows solving this issue in general.

Answer (score 0):

Or change to a single port:

```
digraph G {
    nodesep=0.5;

    graph[ label = ""];
    node [ fontname=Arial fontcolor=black fontsize=24 fixedsize=true width=1.0 height=1.0];
    edge [ fontname=Arial fontcolor=black fontsize=24];

    x0 [label = <> pos="0,2!"]
    x1 [label = <> pos="4,2!" ]
    x2 [label = <> pos="2,0!" ]


    edge[style=solid];
    x0:ne -> x0:nw [ label=<1> ]
    x1 -> x0 [ label=<2> ]
    x2 -> x0 [ label=<3> ]
    x0 -> x1 [ label=<4> ]
    x1:ne -> x1:nw [ label=<6> ]
    x2 -> x1 [ label=<7> ]
    x0 -> x2 [ label=<9> ]
    x1 -> x2 [ label=<8> ]
    x2:s -> x2:s [ label=<0> ]
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a helper node:

```
digraph G {
    nodesep=0.5;

    graph[ label = ""];
    node [ fontname=Arial fontcolor=black fontsize=24 fixedsize=true width=1.0 height=1.0];
    edge [ fontname=Arial fontcolor=black fontsize=24];
    
    {rank=same x0 x1}

    x0 [label = <> pos="0,2!"]
    x1 [label = <> pos="4,2!" ]
    x2 [label = <> pos="2,0!" ]


    edge[style=solid];
    x0:ne -> x0:nw [ label=<1> ]
    x1 -> x0 [ label=<2> ]
    x2 -> x0 [ label=<3> ]
    x0 -> x1 [ label=<4> ]
    x1:ne -> x1:nw [ label=<6> ]
    x2 -> x1 [ label=<7> ]
    x0 -> x2 [ label=<9> ]
    x1 -> x2 [ label=<8> ]
    //x2:sw -> x2:se [ label=<0> ]  
    x2a[shape=dot height=0 width=0 label=<>]
    x2:sw -> x2a:w [dir = none]
    x2a:e -> x2:se [taillabel = 0]
}
```

[image]